# Android (OnePlus device) deep linking issue, tapping SMS app launches my mobile app after deep linking

Tags: android, sms, deep-linking, oneplusone

I am developing an Android app having `deep linking` configured. The deep linking works fine and on clicking of the link my app get launched also.

In one case (`OnePlus` device) when I click the deep link from the `SMS` app it launches my app properly without any issues. But after that if I move to Home screen and try to launch the SMS app again it launches my app instead of the SMS app. This behavior is only noticed on `OnePlus` device. I am using same app on Samsung, Nokia, Oppo and other Android devices and those are fine.

I want the SMS app to get launch instead of my app whenever I launch the SMS app.

In my project's manifest file, launch mode set as SingleTask as follows:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Please suggest if this case can be handled in OnePlus device also with some updates in my app?